# Why I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" in React, while there is no syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, map-function

I'm doing an e-commerce with React and I'm getting an error say

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Which doesn't make sense because I have done the same thing in another component and it works well.

**Here is my code below with the comment on the map function that isn't working. Let me if something isn't clear. I've checked the syntax errors and all works fine**

```
    export class CartItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            product: {},
            failedToLoad: false
        }
    }

    async componentWillMount(){
        let data = await this.getProduct(this.props.product.itemId);
        // let product = data.data.product;
        // this.setState({product: product});
        if (data.data.product) {
            this.setState({product: data.data.product});
        } else {
            this.setState({failedToLoad: true});
        }
    }

    async getProduct(id){

        return await fetchTheQuery(
            `query getProduct($id: String!){
                      
                      product(id: $id){
                        name
                         prices{
                          currency
                          amount
                        }
                      }
                    }`, {id: id}
        )
    }

    render() {
        const {addProduct, productsToPurchase} = this.props.cartContext
        const {selectedCurrency} = this.props.currencyContext
        console.log(this.state.product.prices)

        let productFetched = this.state.product

        if (this.state.failedToLoad){
            return (<div>Something went wrong</div>)
        }
        else if (productFetched){

            return(
                <div>
                    <h2> {this.state.product.name} </h2>

                    <h5>
                        {/*There is an error here*/}
                        { this.state.product.prices.map(
                            price =>{
                                if (price.currency == selectedCurrency){
                                    return( <> { getSymbolFromCurrency(selectedCurrency) +" "+ price.amount }</> )
                                }
                            }
                        )}
                    </h5>

                    <button onClick={() => {
                        addProduct(this.props.product.itemId, this.state.product.prices)
                    }}> Add </button>
                    <h4>{productsToPurchase[this.props.itemIndex].qty}</h4>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            )

        }
        else {
            return <p>Loading............</p>
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `product: {}` Your initial state has product being an empty object. Therefore `product.prices` is undefined. undefined has no `.map` function. Either change the initial state to not be an empty object, or change your code to check for and work with an empty object

Comment: @NicholasTower That's already get overridden over the `{}` when you fetch the data. I use a graphQL endpoint for that. The fetching works fine with the other data like `product.name`.

Comment: Yes, when you eventually download data, `product` will no longer be an empty object. The problem is with the first render. On the first render, you have an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the `this.state.product.prices` exists in the object.
You are getting this error since the collection is empty during the first render.

```
{ this.state.product.prices 
 && this.state.product.prices.map(
    price =>{
       if (price.currency == selectedCurrency){
           return( 
              <> 
               { 
               getSymbolFromCurrency(selectedCurrency) +" "+ price.amount }.  
               </> )
              }
           }
        )}
```

Comment: That worked with me. But what does `this.state.product.prices 
 && this.state.product.prices.map` do?

Comment: Make sure that your collection "prices" is defined inside the "product" and you will not get the error. Your object product doesn't have a valid property "prices" defined during the initial render.

Comment: It is a conditional null/undefined check on the "this.state.product.prices" collection. It checks whether or not the "prices" collection is null/undefined.

Comment: It worked I had to remove `console.log(this.state.product.prices)`